# PHP not inserting form data into DB

Tags: php, forms

So I have a comment post thingy for my blog I've made, but it doesn't seem to be inserting the data. 
Here's the form:

```
<form action='' method='post' name='postComment'>
<label for='name'>Name:</label><br/><input type='text' id='name' name='name''/><br/>
<label for='comment'>Comment:</label><br/><input type='text' id='comment' name='comment' />
<br/><input type='submit' value='Post' name='postComment'/></form></div>
```

The form is processed on the same page in the top part of the page. I use the same way of inserting the data as the blog posts themselves so I know it works. I've also tested the SQL by using phpMyAdmin (obviously removing placeholders)

```
if(!empty($_POST['postComment']))
{
    $date = date("d/m/y g:i:A");
    $name = clean(mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']));
    $comment = clean(mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['comment']));
    if ($stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `comments` (`name`, `comment`, `entry`, `date`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ssis', $name, $comment, $_GET['id'], $date);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, been scratching my head over this one for a day now.

Comment: What error do you get (if any)?

Comment: Also what is the engine of the table, InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: Are you sure $_GET['id'] still exists after you have done a page re-direct with post data?

Comment: Watch out here: - `name='name''` -. You've put two quotes after "name"

Comment: use `try..catch` Or insert `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL)` to get correct error and post it.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2553892/477878) and you'll probably find your problem.

Comment: "InnoDB is the default storage engine on this MySQL server." from phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, thanks for everyone's help. For some reason phpMyAdmin did not set ID as auto-increment even though I set it when I made the table. A simple sql query solved it.

```
ALTER TABLE comments MODIFY id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 1):

The data may need to be cleaned as well, in order to be entered with quotes around it. If you look at your query, you may see the date not being entered like a string, which it should be.

Comment: Also, `$_GET['id']` is bound as an integer, while it's actually a string containing an integer. Unsure how that'd work. As a last thing too, bound strings don't need to be `mysqli_real_escape_string`'d before binding.

Comment: Just changed it to string

Answer (score -1):

Your form action='' is blank, so it's not going anywhere.

Comment: It was PHP_SELF but that just took away the $_GET['id']

Comment: Without declaring an action it will never go anywhere when posted. Use POST, not GET.

Comment: With `action` is blank form will go to the same page.

Comment: That's what I thought @u_mulder

Comment: @Kenzo - a blank action will send the form back to the same page. It's not best practice, but it certainly won't break.

Comment: The form is now set to  <form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?id=" . $_GET['id']; ?>' method='post'

Comment: Not best practice? It's not any practice.

Comment: At least use CodeIgniter for PHP apps, you can then see how PHP works.

Comment: No thanks to CodeIgniter. I'd rather code myself and learn from mistakes.