# Updating a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to edit a Mysql database. Can someone tell me why this is not working, it doesn't update anything

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE Users SET day_started=1 WHERE email='$user_data['email']'");
```

$user_data['email'] works I checked it. I tried echoing it and it did echo the value I wanted. I also checked the database and the value I want it on of the fields in email.

Thank you for your help:)

Comment: What does mysqli_error() say? Have you echo'd out the query to make sure it is correct? Have you run it from the command line? Are you sure there is a row that matches that criteria?

Comment: Is `$con` the correct connection handler?

Comment: There might be a #1064 error because of **`email='$user_data['email']'`**

Comment: Use prepared/parameterized queries.  You're opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$user_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user_data['email']);

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `Users` SET `day_started`='1' WHERE `email`='".$user_email."'");
```

I suspect the answer lies with your not properly embedding a PHP variable in your query string. Check out those sexy full stops on each side of `$user_email`. PHP loves it when you do that.

I also sanitized your input and stuff, and formatted your query with backticks because PHP also loves that.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The question is "Can someone tell me why this is not working".

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is not working is because you are using part of an array in a string. In order to do that, you have a few options:

1. Use curly braces around it:

   `"UPDATE Users SET day_started=1 WHERE email='{$user_data['email']}'"`
2. Concatenation:

   `"UPDATE Users SET day_started=1 WHERE email='".$user_data['email']."'"`
3. Use temporary variables:

   `$email = $user_data['email'];`

   Then in your string:

   `"UPDATE Users SET day_started=1 WHERE email='$email'"`
4. (bonus, I just learned this myself) Remove the quotes around `email`:

   `"UPDATE Users SET day_started=1 WHERE email='$user_data[email]'"`

   It actually surprised me that this works and doesn't throw a notice/warning. The following, however, **does** produce a notice, so be careful (it needs to be in a double quoted string or probably heredoc):

   `echo $user_data[email];`

   > **Notice**: Use of undefined constant email - assumed 'email'

However the fact that you are even asking this poses some great problems. First, you should turn on [error_reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/php-how-do-i-enable-error-reporting). Therefore if any error occurs, it will yell and scream at you if all goes well. Second, you should [do the same for mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552545/mysqli-prepared-statements-error-reporting). And finally, if you're using mysqli, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). This is precisely what they're for.

Comment: I did try using temporary variables but it did not work

Comment: You need to be more specific about what "did not work" is supposed to mean. But like I said in my answer, prepared statements are the way to go. Seriously. Forget doing it any other way.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of that the single quotes matches which is nearest to it.
so in your code `email='$user_data['email']'` ,the first single quotes in`'$` just matches that in `['email` .to avoid this,you can modify your sql code like this:

```
"UPDATE Users SET day_started=1 WHERE email='$user_data[email]'",this really works.
```

or just do like this:

```
$post_email = $user_data['email'];
"UPDATE Users SET day_started=1 WHERE email='$post_email'";
```