# php - mysqli prepare statement error - procedure style

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling, prepared-statement

I just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552545/mysqli-prepared-statements-error-reporting) it explains clearly for object oriented style error handling.

[This](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php) page also explains the same.

I want to know how to find whether a prepared statement fails, and what is the error.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare(ConnectionObject,Query);
if($stmt == false)
{
    // Found statement fails
    // How to find what is the error
    // mysqli_stmt_error($stmt); It will fail because $stmt is boolean[false].
}
```

How to find the exact error?

Comment: Then use `mysqli_error()` with your connection handle.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: I tried that already. It returns something `<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i>` . I dont understand any error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php):

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare(ConnectionObject, $query);
if(!$stmt) {
    printf("Cannot prepare query <%s>. Error message: %s\n", 
           $query, mysqli_error(ConnectionObject));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mureinik. Can you please explain `<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i>`. I just got this from `var_dump(mysqli_error(ConnectionObject))`

Comment: @GopsAB this is a var_dump of an empty string (`''`), indicating there has been no error before you called `mysqli_error`.

Comment: What is the reason for down-vote?