# Mysqli statement fails to execute WHERE NOT clause

Tags: php, mysqli

can anyone see why this statement is not working? 
im attempting to select all except  the value in $creator, I know the value is set because a echo statement just below the query reveals the value,

```
$this->res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM escrow WHERE name !=$creator  ");
```

Ive discovered that this works:
    $this->res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM challenges_created WHERE name !='$creator'");

but this is not working:
    $this->res = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM challenges_created WHERE name !='$creator'");

obviously the syntax is wrong somewhere in the latter of the 2

Comment: Define "isn't working"? For mysqli debugging tips, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552545/mysqli-prepared-statements-error-reporting What type is `name`? If it's a varchar, you may be missing quotes.

Comment: the query does not do what im asking it to do, which is extract all from a table except where name is  the variable, the variable is a name under a name column in a MySQL table

Comment: What *does* it do then?

Comment: it does nothing, does the query look correct?

Comment: Impossible to tell - but you can have mysqli tell you *yourself* what is wrong here by using proper error reporting. Check out the link above

Comment: `$this->res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM escrow WHERE name !='$creator'  ");`

Comment: Not knowing your table structure, I am going to make a strong guess that `$creator` contains a _string_ value, which must be single quoted in a SQL statement.  See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11321508/541091) for examples. And if the value `$creator` originates from user input, you should be using [`prepare()/bind_param()/execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead of passing the variable into the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
$this->res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM escrow WHERE name !='$creator'");
```

Comment: Please add an explanation, why he should do that, so that it is possible to learn form your answer.

Comment: @sam , your example performs like mines, it does not return anything at all, and there are other names in the "name" column,

Comment: Pinkie, basically the $creator should be in single quotation '$creator'. It is because we are checking against the $creator string.

Comment: @user5420896, You are missing single quotes. For example '$creator'.