# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\k24Electronics\admin\Supplier\import.php on line 13 Call Stack

Tags: php, php-5.4

```
function add_product( $product_name, $product_brand, $product_type,
                      $product_description,$product_price, $number, 
                      $reservefee, $status,$image,$supplier_id )

{
     global $data,$sth;
     $con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","eeee");
     $sth = $con->prepare( "INSERT INTO products
                                (product_name,product_brand,product_type,
                                product_description,product_price,number,reservefee,
                                status,image,supplier_id) 
                            VALUES(0,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" );

     $sth->bind_param('ssssiiisbi', $product_name, $product_brand, $product_type,$product_description,$product_price, $number, $reservefee, $status,$image,$supplier_id);

    $sth->execute();

    $data []= array(
    'product_name' => $product_name,
    'product_brand' => $product_brand,
    'product_type' => $product_type,
    'product_description' => $product_description,
    'product_price' => $product_price,
    'number' => $number,
    'reservefee' => $reservefee,
    'status' => $status,
    'image' => $image,
    'supplier_id' => $supplier_id
    );
}
```

Comment: It seems there is an error in your query...

Comment: And line 13 **is which line??**

Comment: @RiggsFolly should be the one with bind_param on it.

Comment: The prepare failed probably an issue in the query. You cont bother to check for an error so the code tries to use `$stmt` which is now `= false` and is not an object. Therefore you get the error when you try and use it in the `bind_value`

Comment: @AdamForbis Yea I know, but it is useful to remind the questioner of the sort of information they shoudl provide when asking for help. NOTE: There is no `<?php` line in his code so we dont know where abouts in 1000 lines of code he took this particular snippet from

Comment: Your INSERT statement specifies 10 fields yet you offer 11 values...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552545/mysqli-prepared-statements-error-reporting to learn more about prepared statements error handling

Comment: What is the 0 value? and you should use single quotes **'** , somwhere in the string you have **number** and seems the PHP interprets it.

Comment: line 13  $sth->bind_param('ssssiiisb', $product_name, $product_brand, $product_type, $product_description,$product_price, $number, $reservefee, $status,$image);

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in `$con->prepare`, so it has returned `false` therfore the  `bind_param` has failed as it is not working on a `mysqli_statement` object.

Try deleting one of `?` from your VALUES clause in the prepare, because you are telling mysql to insert 11 parameters into 10 column names.

Comment: i have removed some fields but it is not working.  $con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","electronicsshop");
 $sth = $con->prepare( "INSERT INTO products('product_name','product_brand','product_type','product_description',product_price,number,reservefee,'status','image') VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" );
 $sth->bind_param('ssssiiisb', $product_name, $product_brand, $product_type, $product_description,$product_price, $number, $reservefee, $status,$image);

$sth->execute();

Comment: @MurithiH Randomly changing things is not the solution. Apply a little logic to what you are doing

Comment: Now you have 10 columns names and 9 `?` parameters **Its simple mathematics!**

Comment: When you get that right, remember you have to then provide the same (correct) number of values in the `bind_param()` statement as well to match the number of `?` in the VALUE clause

Comment: @MurithiH PS: nobody can read code in a comment. If you want to add additional information then EDIT you question. Add more info at the bottom and label its as "Additional Info" or something

Comment: I have found another way to insert the data. thanks all