# I'm using php 5.6.25 and trying to filter the input, but it is only entering the data once into mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I've tried a few ways of filtering and when I do I can only insert into the table once, the id is set to auto increment.
This is how variables get defined.

```
<form action = "php/createaccount.php" method = "post">
First Name <br /> <input type ="text" placeholder="First name" name = "fname"><br />
Last Name <br /> <input type ="text" placeholder="Last name" name = "lname"><br />
User Name <br /> <input type ="text" placeholder="Username" name = "uname"><br />
Password <br /> <input type ="text" placeholder="Password" name = "pword"><br />
School Name <br /> <input type ="text" placeholder="School name" name = "sname"><br />
Email <br /> <input type ="text" placeholder="Email" name = "email"> <br /> 
<input type = "submit" value = "Create Account">
</form>
```

This is the createaccount.php page

```
<?php
error_reporting (-1); ini_set ("display_errors", "On");
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "root" , "" , "epicreads");
//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, email, uname, sname)
VALUES
(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$sql->bind_param('sssss', $fname, $lname, $email, $uname, $sname);
$sql->execute();

//Password and password security
//Set the cost
$cost = 10;

// Create a random salt
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');

// Hash the password with the salt
$hash = crypt($pword, $salt);

//Post into table
$pword = "INERT INTO users (pword)
values
('$_POST[pword]')";

//Echo
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));

echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

this is the updated createaccount.php page
UPDATE:
With error reporting on it is saying that column 'fname' cannot be null
[This is my table structure in mysqli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkBgb.png)

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: if you can only insert into db once, then something is failing; check for errors.

Comment: btw, where are you pulling in those variables/post arrays from?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is.  You claim you can successfully insert into the database once, and I see only one `INSERT` statement being executed.  So what isn't working?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Without seeing the variable definition, how can you conclude the OP isn't using hash?

Comment: I cannot make that conclusion @Manikiran. Let's just call it a hunch.

Comment: I don't now how to check for errors. And what are you referring to when you ask where I'm getting them from? I am getting them from the user. I am incredibly new to php so sorry if I don't know what you are talking about

Comment: Visit and read through these http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and apply it to your code. If you're going to want to learn and be a serious coder, then those are 2 (of a few more) basic tools you need to use during development/testing.

Comment: I'm testing filtering to work on the user input and when I do so I can only insert into the table once, but after that I can't do it again. I need to be able to have this happen as many times as needed.

Comment: Put in error_reporting (-1); ini_set ("display_errors", "On"); at the top of your pho file and see what is the output the first time (when it works) and the other times (when it stops working)

Comment: Show us how $fname, $lname, $email, $uname, $sname, $pword are defined.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here:

```
//Post into table
$pword = "INERT INTO users (pword)
values
('$_POST[pword]')";
```

You want to `INSERT` with an S.

Also:

```
// Hash the password with the salt
$hash = crypt($pword, $salt);
```

you're hashing the SQL statement, not the variable.

As recommended in comments you should be using `password_hash`, it appears you have a `cost` array value which is typical of password_hash so maybe you copy/pasted it from somewhere where it is used, go back and read the rest of the syntax.

Using your own salts is not advised.

Your issue here:

> With error reporting on it is saying that column 'fname' cannot be null

Is because you're trying to enter a empty row; your password SQL, above, is inserting a password value into MySQL but you're probably wanting to `UPDATE` an existing row rather than `INSERT` a new row with just a password on it.

So what you should do is research `password_hash` and edit your password table column to be at least 72 characters long and then insert the password at the same time as you insert the rest of the data into the table.

If you need to edit a row that already exists you should use the [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) MySQL function.

You also have your

```
//Echo  
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
```

will run every time the script runs, regardless as if there is an error or if it is picked up. This is not the way to detect Object orientated MySQL errors. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553892/3536236) with a good rundown on how to detect MySQL errors in PHP.

There is also no guide as to where your variables come from? I assume you're already working with then before they reach the SQL INSERT but considering you are researching input filtering, I see no evidence of any input filtering on your question code. I hope you're not using global variables, typically posted for varaibles are accessible as `$_POST['name']` superglobals once a form has been submitted.

---

```
<?php
error_reporting (-1);
ini_set ("display_errors", "On");
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "root" , "" , "epicreads");
//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

/***
New password construct:
//Password and password security
//Set the cost    
***/
$option['cost'] = 10;
$password = password_hash($_POST['pword'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $option);


$sql = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, email, uname, sname, pword)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)");
$sql->bind_param('ssssss', $fname, $lname, $email, $uname, $sname,$password);
$check = $sql->execute();

// execute() can fail for various reasons. 
// And may it be as stupid as someone tripping over the network cable
// 2006 "server gone away" is always an option
if ( $check === false ) {
    //much better than a die statement: 
    error_log('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($sql->error));
}
else {
    echo "1 record added";
}

$sql->close();
```

Comment: I tried the code provided above, and it isn't reporting an error, or inputting into the table. Also thank you for the useful links

Comment: Use the links to MySQL Error logging to track where your error is occuring. @DamianO'Keefe