# Connection phpmyadmin and html

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin, relational-database

Greeting dear programmers, i have problem in connecting mydatabase. I create three tables under one database. I put relationship for three table. After i put it i add phpcode to connect it. But it doesnt want to work. Before this,i try connect use that code. It works. But for this it doesnt want. I dont know is it because of the table relationship or got any error on my html form. Any developer pls help me to tell my problem. A lot of Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = '';
$mysqli=new MySQLi('127.0.0.1','root','','accounts');

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$option1 = $_POST['option1'];
$option2 = $_POST['option2'];
$option3 = $_POST['option3'];
$option4 = $_POST['option4'];
$option5 = $_POST['option5'];
$option6 = $_POST['option6'];


                $sql ="INSERT INTO menubar(option1,option2,option3,option4,option5,option6)"
                ."VALUES ('$option1','$option2','$option3','$option4','$option5','$option6')";

                if($mysqli->query($sql)=== true) {
                          $_SESSION['message'] ='Registration successful!
                          Added to the database!';
                     header("location:confirmnormal.php");
                      }
                      else {
                          $_SESSION['message'] = "User could not be added to the database!";
                      }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Normal</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<?=$_SESSION['message']?>
<table align="center" >
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
<tr>
<td>
 Enter Menu Bar:
</td>
 &nbsp;<td> 
<input type="text" placeholder="Personal Information" name="option1" required/>

<tr><td></td><td>
<input type="text" placeholder="Career Aspirations" name="option2" required />
</td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td> 
 <input type="text" placeholder="Educational Background" name="option3" required />
 </td></tr>
 <tr><td></td> <td> <input type="text" placeholder="Skills" name="option4" required /></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td> <td><input type="text" placeholder="Language Proficiency" name="option5" required /></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="Job Preference" name="option6" required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="login" value="register" class="btn-login"/>
</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: The biggest problem is that you're not checking if the `$_POST` variables are set with `isset()` before trying to insert them into the database. If they're not set, you will throw an error (which you're not catching). Make sure to add [**fallback logic**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552545/mysqli-prepared-statements-error-reporting) to debug issues. You should also really use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent to avoid SQL injection, and your HTML is invalid (though that shouldn't cause any problems).

Answer (score 0):

Check the POST using `isset()` also check the POST by using form submit

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $option1 = $_POST['option1'];
    $option2 = $_POST['option2'];
    $option3 = $_POST['option3'];
    $option4 = $_POST['option4'];
    $option5 = $_POST['option5'];
    $option6 = $_POST['option6'];


            $sql ="INSERT INTO menubar(option1,option2,option3,option4,option5,option6)"
            ."VALUES ('$option1','$option2','$option3','$option4','$option5','$option6')";

            if($mysqli->query($sql)=== true) {
                      $_SESSION['message'] ='Registration successful!
                      Added to the database!';
                 header("location:confirmnormal.php");
                  }
                  else {
                      $_SESSION['message'] = "User could not be added to the database!";
                  }
}
```