# PHP Replace character with string from an array

Tags: php, mysql

For mysql I use format:

```
$sql = "select * from table where area_id = ? and item_id = ?";
```

Then prepare and bind the parameters etc. If the query fails and I log the $sql variable then I get exactly the string above which isn't that useful. What I want is the sql string with the bound values in. As I understand it there is no easy way to do this so I am thinking I can do something like:

```
sql_log(str_replace('?', array($area_id, $item_id), $sql));
```

To get something like this in my log:

```
"select * from table where area_id = West and item_id = West" (spot the error!)
```

So I know what my error is. But it doesn't work. I get this:

```
"select * from table where area_id = Array and item_id = Array"
```

Comment: Are you using `mysqli` or `PDO` to prepare your statements?

Comment: I am using mysqli

Comment: Solution here is `preg_replace_callback` as your items are always `?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQLi prepared statements error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552545/mysqli-prepared-statements-error-reporting)

Answer (score 2):

Use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function

```
$sql = "select * from table where area_id = ? and item_id = ?";
$replace = array('area_id', 'item_id');
echo preg_replace_callback('/\?/', function($x) use(&$replace) { return array_shift($replace);}, $sql);
// select * from table where area_id = area_id and item_id = item_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `mysqli` does not have a good way to get just the query. You could use a method to do the replacement of your parameters:

```
function populateSql ( string $sql, array $params ) : string {
    foreach($params as $value)
        $sql = preg_replace ( '[\?]' , "'" . $value . "'" , $sql, 1 );
    return $sql;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
sprintf('select * from table where area_id = %s and item_id = %s', $area_id, $item_id);
```

or

```
sprintf('select * from table where area_id = "%s" and item_id = "%s"', $area_id, $item_id);
```

if your fields in the database are integers the %s you have to replace it with %d and do not use quotes

Comment: That won't bind properly!

Comment: @funnyfish this question isn't about constructing a viable sql query.  This is about replacing the placeholders with the bound values for the sake of storing in an error log.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a beautiful helper for just that.

```
/**
  * Replace a given value in the string sequentially with an array.
  *
  * @param  string  $search
  * @param  array   $replace
  * @param  string  $subject
  * @return string
  */
function replaceArray($search, array $replace, $subject)
{
    $segments = explode($search, $subject);

    $result = array_shift($segments);

    foreach ($segments as $segment) {
        $result .= (array_shift($replace) ?? $search).$segment;
    }

    return $result;
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col_b = ? AND col_b = ?';

$bindings = [
  'col_a' => 'value_a',
  'col_b' => 'value_b',
];

echo replaceArray('?', $bindings, $sql);

// SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col_b = value_a AND col_b = value_b
```

Source: [Str::replaceArray()](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Support/Str.html#method_replaceArray)