# How to write to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

I used `localhost` and everything works fine, however, when I hosted it in digital ocean, certain `POST` functions don't write to the mysql database.

I've tried using `Postman` to test the code, and it returns `200 OK` and `error writing to database`.

My `db_functions` code:

```
 public function insertNewListing($name,$imgPath,$price,$listingId,$descriptions,$packageOne,$packageTwo,$moreDescriptions,$itinerary,$imgPathTwo,$imgPathThree)
{
    $stmt= $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `Longhouses`(`Name`, `Link`,`Price`,`ListingId`,`descriptions`,`PackageOne`,`PackageTwo`,`MoreDescription`,`Itinerary`,`ImageTwo`,`ImageThree`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)") or die ($this->conn->error);

    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssss",$name,$imgPath,$price,$listingId,$descriptions,$packageOne,$packageTwo,$moreDescriptions,$itinerary,$imgPathTwo,$imgPathThree);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    if($result)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

My `add_listing` function:

```
<?php
require_once '../../db_functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

if(isset($_POST['name'])&&isset($_POST['imgPath'])&&isset($_POST['price'])&&isset($_POST['listingId'])&&isset($_POST['descriptions'])&&isset($_POST['packageOne'])&& isset($_POST['packageTwo'])&&isset($_POST['moreDescriptions'])&& isset($_POST['itinerary'])&& isset($_POST['imgPathTwo'])&& isset($_POST['imgPathThree']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$imgPath = $_POST['imgPath'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$listingId = $_POST['listingId'];
$descriptions = $_POST['descriptions'];
$packageOne = $_POST['packageOne'];
$packageTwo = $_POST['packageTwo'];
$moreDescriptions = $_POST['moreDescriptions'];
$itinerary = $_POST['itinerary'];
$imgPathTwo = $_POST['imgPathTwo'];
$imgPathThree = $_POST['imgPathThree'];


$result = $db->insertNewListing($name,$imgPath,$price,$listingId,$descriptions,$packageOne,$packageTwo,$moreDescriptions,$itinerary,$imgPathTwo,$imgPathThree);
if($result)
    echo json_encode("ADD LISTING SUCCESFUL");
else
    echo json_encode("error writing to database");

}
```

Comment: you should catch the error.'error writing to database'  is not usefull. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552545/mysqli-prepared-statements-error-reporting

Comment: Well, what does the http servers error log file say what the actual issue is?

Comment: solved the problem. Incompatible PHP version.