# How can I collect result from prepare statement PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

I can't collect the results of my query in this function :

```php
<?php
function getBestScore()
{
    require_once ('connection.php');

    $idJoueur = session_id();

    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT bestScore FROM Player WHERE ID = ?'))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $idJoueur);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        $data = $result->fetch_assoc();

        $bestScore = $data;

        if (!(empty($bestScore)))
        {
            header("Location: ../index.php");
        }

        return $bestScore;
    }
    else
    {
        $error = $conn->errno . ' ' . $conn->error;
        echo $error;
    }

}
```

My connection works, I tried `fetch_assoc()`, `store_result()` but I failed every time.

Comment: I tried with $data['bestScore'] too

Comment: And the if(empty(...)) is a test

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't have any error, I just can't get the value of my best score

Comment: You really need to check for errors at every step. Maybe useful: [MySQLi prepared statements error reporting.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552545/mysqli-prepared-statements-error-reporting)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to select data then try the following

```
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT bestScore FROM Player WHERE ID = ?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i',$idJoueur);
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($result);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    if (!(empty($result))) {
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried and it didn't work

Comment: If you get a blank result then please check the id value and if the table has records.