# PHP GET Query returning null on a database with data

Tags: php, postman

I have a php script to query from a table LABCPD which has one entry, however the GET call in POSTMAN is  retuning status OK with no errors but not returning any data,  there are no syntax errors or permission / access issues:

Script:

```
<?php
/**
 * CPD Manual porject.
 * Files will be hosted on mooneycallans.com server
 * SQL inj. safe
 */

require_once 'headers.php';

// Add debugging output to console in POSTMAN and error log

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL');

// Make suer the database on server we are reading / writing to as in UTF-8standard

   mysqli_set_charset('m558405_tests','utf8');
   



require_once 'headers.php';

// Create a connection to the databse 'm558405_tests DB 
$conn = new mysqli(hostName,usernamePlaceHolder,passwordPlaceHolder,databaseName);

$table = "LABCPD";


// Check DB connection and return  a JSON error if cannot connect

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    $errorResponse = array(
        'error' => 'Connection failed',
        'message' => $conn->connect_error
    );
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    http_response_code(500); // Set the HTTP response code to indicate an internal server error
    echo json_encode($errorResponse);
    exit(); // Terminate the script
}



    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET'){
        if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
            /// Sfaely escape the user input and use a prepared statement
            $id = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    
            // Prepare an SQL statement with a placeholder
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = ?");
    
            // Bind the escaped user input to the placeholder in the SQL statement
            $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
    
            // Execute the prepared statement
            $stmt->execute();
    
            // Get the result of the query
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
            // Fetch the data as an associative array
            $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
    
            // Close the prepared statement
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            $data = array();
    
            // Prepare an SQL statement to fetch all rows
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
    
            // Execute prepared statement
            $stmt->execute();
    
            // Get the result of the query
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
            while ($d = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $data[] = $d;
            }
    
            // Close the prepared statement
            $stmt->close();
        }
    
        // Return the JSON data
        exit(json_encode($data, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR, 512));
    }
```

Database has one entry:
[image: Database with one row]

My question is does it look like there is an issue with PHP snippet or could I be missing something else?

Comment: For a start, this lacks the `<?php` stanza. Also, this Q should come with a [mcve].

Comment: Well what should I add - the GET url ? I can do but they were no errors , I am unsure as Last time  posted a question about php I was marked down for having too much detail.

Comment: Ideally, you'd run the script from the commandline in order to avoid the dependency on the way this is served and how the parameters are passed and decoded.

Comment: Do u mean something like hosting the database and php scripts on a local sever using MAMP? I’ll give it a try, thanks

Comment: You haven't shown how `$conn` is set up, maybe in an include - do you have error reporting on, could the script be failing during the connection?  How about `$table`, is that defined somewhere?

Comment: just added that code now, I set up DB and PHP scripts in MAMP and it works fine, so has to be something to with config odf remote web server

Comment: Note that `ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL');` is NOT the same as `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`. I believe you want the latter. No idea what result you might be getting by trying to set that to a string instead of an integer constant.

Comment: You have no error checking on any of your database calls. Any one of them could fail, but you're assuming they'll all work.

Comment: Please, read [mcve]. Nobody here can guess what `headers.php` contains! Also, reduce the scope of your code as much as possible, in order to circle in on what is the cause of the problem. Lastly, please retake the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Good you are checking errors in the connection, but you need to do the same with your queries, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552545/mysqli-prepared-statements-error-reporting. Also, keep it simple - until you know what is going on just `var_dump($data)`, separately, before any `exit()` or `json_encode()`ing which might confuse the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the pointers.
The issue was with the below line of code. When I removed the JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR , a GET request replies with all data from that query. The remote web server runs PHP 7.0, and JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR was added on PHP 7.3;

```
exit(json_encode($data, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR, 512));
```